# I am trying to set a col to the right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Well I am trying bootstrap 4 and playing around with col and row etc.... I want to float a part of the contact form to the right I tried justify-content-end float right and many styling ways none of them worked i am new with development and stuff so excuse me thanks this is my code

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="contact-info">
      <h2>Contact Us</h2>
      <h4>We would love to hear from you !</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
<style>.col-md-3{background: #EF7F1A; padding: 3%;height: 35em;border-top-left-radius: 0.5rem;border-bottom-left-radius: 0.5rem;} </style>
```

[https://ibb.co/1n4ynmp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcngF.png)

Comment: Try using css's flexbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put the rest of the form into a `col-md-9` element and place that *before*  the `col-md-3` element in your HTML.

Comment: the form is actually in a col-md-9 :/

Comment: and in which order are they?

Comment: if they are in the correct order, there has to be some class applied to their common parent element which turns the order around - look for that and remove it (if applicable)